# cakephp print data from another model

Tags: cakephp, orm, controller, cakephp-3.0

My problem is this. I have a controller "FacsController", and a method.

```
public function access()
{
     $facs = $this->Facs->find()->all();
     return $facs;
}
```

This method works perfectly, data is returned properly.
But what I need is to call this method within another controller, "PagesController".

```
public function display()
{
     $var = new  FacsController();
     $var->access();
     $this->set('vars', $var);
     $this->set('_serialize', ['vars']);
}
```

Unfortunately here I do not get the data returned from the FacsController.
Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want data from a model, then you use the model, not a controller! If you ever feel the need that one controller needs to access another controller, then this is almost always an indicator for a failure in your application design. Also you never instantiate controllers yourself (unless in unit tests maybe)!

If you want to keep things DRY, create proper custom methods in your model (table class) and use them to encapsulate further logic.

That being said, like in every other controller, load the model via `$this->loadModel()`, or even `TableRegistry::get()`.

```
$var = $this->loadModel('Facs')->find()->all();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Loading Additional Models](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Getting Instances of a Table Class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class)**